# set margin to a custom view group item view liked edittext

Tags: android, android-custom-view, viewgroup, android-viewgroup, android-layoutparams

I am trying to create a custom view group and created it successfully but unable to set margin to an child of viewgroup like editext
Following is my code,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import mp.R;

public class EditTextLoader extends ViewGroup {

private EditText materialEditText;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageView imgErrorRefresh;

public EditTextLoader(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public EditTextLoader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public EditTextLoader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}


private void init(@NonNull Context context) {
    setClipToPadding(false);

    materialEditText = new EditText(context);
    materialEditText.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    materialEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    materialEditText.setHint(context.getString(R.string.vShutt_textPickup));
    addView(materialEditText);

    progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
    addView(progressBar);

    imgErrorRefresh = new ImageView(context);
    imgErrorRefresh.setImageResource(R.drawable.editext_success);
    addView(imgErrorRefresh);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    widthMeasureSpec = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = 0;

    // 2. Measure the ProfilePhoto
    measureChild(imgErrorRefresh, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    height = Math.max(materialEditText.getMeasuredHeight(), height);
    measureChild(materialEditText, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, height);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int height = getHeight();
    int leftWidthImage = right - imgErrorRefresh.getMeasuredWidth();
    progressBar.layout(leftWidthImage, 0, right, height);
    materialEditText.layout(0, 0, leftWidthImage - 20, height);
}
```

}

Whenever I try to set margin to the element I got the following exception,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6593)
                                                                        at mp.EditTextLoader.onMeasure(EditTextLoader.java:73)
```

It happens, whenever I add the following code,

```
    measureChildWithMargins(
            materialEditText,0,0,20,0);
```

I have started by looking at the following examples but unable to solve my issue,

[Measure, Layout, Draw, Repeat: Custom Views and ViewGroups
by Huyen Tue Dao](https://academy.realm.io/posts/360andev-huyen-tue-dao-measure-layout-draw-repeat-custom-views-and-viewgroups-android/)

[Custom ViewGroups by Sriram](https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/custom-viewgroups/)